# The CP Theme appears to be locked. How do I change it?

Tags: control-panel, cp-themes

I am seeing some strange Control Panel formatting in a site I work on. The site is running EE 2.6.1 and in general works fine, however, I cannot change the Control Panel theme. It defaults to Corporate and even if I remove Corporate from cp_themes from the server, it still displays Corporate. Any suggestions on how to change that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in system/expressionengine/config/config.php - you'll probably find the theme is hardcoded there with `$config['cp_theme'] = 'corporate'`